# ASP.NET Core - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to '.Identity.ApplicationUser'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the record for the current logged in user in ASP.NET Core Web API Application by getting the id of the user from ApplicationUser in IdentityDbContext.

I have these services:

```
public interface IUserService
{
   string GetCurrentUserId();
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private HtmlEncoder _htmlEncoder;

    public UserService(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
    )
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public string GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        string currentUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        return currentUserId;
    }
}

    public StudentProfileDto FromStudentProfileToStudentDto(Student student)
    {
        var studentDto = new StudentProfileDto()//;
        {
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.LastName,
            AdmissionNumber = student.AdmissionNumber,
        };

        return studentDto;
    }
```

Then I applied it here:

```
public interface IStudentService
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(ApplicationUser user = null);
}

    public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(ApplicationUser user = null)
    {
        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var studentProfile = await _unitOfWork.StudentRepository.GetAll();
        var studentDtoProfile = studentProfile.Where(x => x.UserId == Convert.ToInt64(user)).Select(c => mapper.FromStudentProfileToStudentDto(c)).ToList();

        return studentDtoProfile;
    }
```

BaseRepository:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public BaseRepository(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var list = await _entities.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }

    public async Task Insert(T entity)
    {
        entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.IsDeleted = false;
        await _entities.AddAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IBaseRepository<Student> StudentRepository { get; }

    void SaveChanges();
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DDMDbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DDMDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private readonly IBaseRepository<Student> _studentRepository;
    public IBaseRepository<Student> StudentRepository => _studentRepository ?? new BaseRepository<Student>(_context);
```

Then finally called it from the controller:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile()
    {
        long userId = Convert.ToInt64(_userService.GetCurrentUserId());
        return await _studentService.GetStudentProfile(userId);
    }
```

But I got this error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'Identity.ApplicationUser'

It highlights userId in:

> return await _studentService.GetStudentProfile(userId);

What do I do to resolve this?

**Updated Code:**

```
public interface IStudentService
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(long? user);
}

    public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(long? user)
    {
        var mapper = new EntityMapper();
        var studentProfile = await _unitOfWork.StudentRepository.GetAll();
        var studentDtoProfile = studentProfile.Where(x => x.UserId == Convert.ToInt64(user)).Select(c => mapper.FromStudentProfileToStudentDto(c)).ToList();

        return studentDtoProfile;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile()
    {
        long userId = Convert.ToInt64(_userService.GetCurrentUserId());
        return await _studentService.GetStudentProfile(userId);
    }
```

Comment: Change `Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(ApplicationUser user = null)` to accept a long or add a new method that will.

Comment: @Jasen - How and what do I change it to?

Comment: `GetStudentProfile(long userId)` now it accepts a long parameter.

Comment: @Jasen - I also have Ienumerable in BaseRepository which I called as GetAll(). How do I effect it in all. See my code.

Comment: Why do you want to change GetAll() ????

Answer (score 1):

In your GetStudentProfile method,  it accepts an ApplicationUser as a parameter not a long.

Comment: I did that because the currentUser id I'm collecting in ApplicationUser is long.

Comment: I think method should be as this: public Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(long? user);
}

Comment: If I use that, I don't know how else I'll be able to get the currentUser Id.

Comment: In your controller, you already get the user id as;       
long userId = Convert.ToInt64(_userService.GetCurrentUserId());               which is correct. So only change that method parameter is the service

Comment: When I changed it as you advised, it returns empty record. And yet there's a record for the profile

Comment: Could you please post the updated code?

Comment: I have posted the updated code below the old code

Comment: What am I not getting right, that's it's not displaying any record?

Comment: Any error message?  what value is being passed for the method???.                           
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(long? user)

Comment: Since we are getting a long userId from _userService.GetCurrentUserId() method, we don't need to set the user parameter to nullable in GetStudentProfile method. I have changed it to long user.  public async Task<IEnumerable<StudentProfileDto>> GetStudentProfile(long user)